# extracting names and associated labels from text with language model

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, bert-language-model

I am trying to extract information from scientific literature on microalgae and i need to be able to scan a text for various names and find their corresponding category.

As an simple example, say I have 3 names (Peter, John, Linda) and I want to find their job title from this list of titles (Carpenter, Fisherman, Ninja) and this is the text:
"Peter lives in a house he build himself, he is a great carpenter. Linda likes to run marathons when she is not busy running her own business. John is 40 and lives from fishing"

I would like a response like so (Peter = carpenter, John = Fisherman, Linda = NA).
Currently I am trying bert but can only find a way to extract a single label from a text and I cannot find a way to contextualise it to the person in question.

Does anyone have suggestion on how to go about this?

(UPDATE) A more specific example would be using this text:
"Nannochloropsis gaditana is in the genus of Nannochloropsis comprising six known species all of which are unicellur. Unlike these species all species in the genus Arthrospira are filamentous such as Arthrospira platensis."

Here i need to extract:  Nannochlorpsis gaditana = unicellur, Arthrospira platensis = filamentous.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are looking into is called [named entity recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) and there are both traditional NLP models and LLMs trained for this type of task.

For example, for the former this is commonly done in [spaCy](https://spacy.io/):

```py
text = '''
Peter lives in a house he build himself, he is a great carpenter. 
Linda likes to run marathons when she is not busy running her own business. 
John is 40 and lives from fishing
'''

import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
ner = nlp(text)

for word in ner.ents:
    print(word.text,word.label_)
```

```
Peter PERSON
Linda PERSON
John PERSON
40 DATE
```

However, as you can see, these models are not perfect, and also have a specific sets of entity types they are trained to recognize by default. If you want to recognize your own custom entity types, you would need to find the right pre-trained model for this use case or [train your own](https://towardsdatascience.com/train-ner-with-custom-training-data-using-spacy-525ce748fab7).

Comment: So, in running your example i notice it extracts names. My example is maybe not the best as what i would be extracting is related to taxonomic species names. E.g I look for Nannocholoropsis gaditana in the text and will be looking if it single celled or filamenteous.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, you'd likely need to train your own model for your specific use case. You may be better off using simpler techniques like a dictionary-based key terms search, depending upon what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

The approach NLP from scratch described is correct, but there are other ways.

**Current LLMS such as chatgpt are sometimes able to perform this kind of task without any additional training.**

For example, I used this prompt

> Based on the following text, which species or genus are unicelular, and which filamentous?
> Please answer in the format "Genus: unicelular"
> Nannochloropsis gaditana is in the genus of Nannochloropsis comprising six known species all of which are unicelular. Unlike these species all species in the genus Arthrospira are filamentous such as Arthrospira platensis.

And h2oGPT [Model: mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1] on extract mode [accesible here](https://gpt.h2o.ai/?_gl=1*1ebu9dd*_ga*NDgwMTA3NDE3LjE3MDIzMDM1NDU.*_ga_7C4SBBBJ5L*MTcwMjMwMzU0NS4xLjEuMTcwMjMwMzU1OC40Ny4wLjA.) gave me this answer

> Sure, here's the answer based on the given text:
> *
> Nannochloropsis: unicellular
> * Arthrospira: filamentous

**The prompt could be seriously improved to better fit the results you desire and the model you decide to use, and you should play around with it and try to optimize it.**

That said, this approach could also definitely work to achieve what you desire without training. Good luck!